# Symfony2 Entity with DBAL (No ORM)

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm working on a SF2 project where I can't use Doctrine2 as ORM, meaning that I already have a database with tables and data. I have to use plain SQL in my controller (I'm currently using DBAL to do that), and I have to create object in order to represent things.

When I used to work with Doctrine2, I create Entity by app/console doctrine:generate:entity and Doctrine2 is handling the whole stuff (update, persisting...)

But now, as I'm using DBAL, how can I create object (can I call it entity even if i'm not using ORM?) to fit my need ?

I was planning to do like usual : create an entity folder in my bundle with entities as objects without the ORM annotations, and create a method where I retrieve data from database using SQL (result of the query in an array) and hydrating it using getters/setters from the object.

Is it a good idea or do you have a better solution ? I'm beginning with SF2 and I read that some people create a service to retrieve data and then using data transformer to transform data into the object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing Active Record pattern. For this purpose you can use Propel that has native integration with Symfony. Read about it on [Symfony's official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/propel.html).

Also I would recommend you to use ORM. You can set your mapping with existing tables as you want: you can even omit some fields if you don't need them in entity. And Doctrine ORM will do all the hard work for you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, however I can't use Doctrine because it will generate tables from my entities and I have to keep database structure as it

Comment: It will not generate tables if you will not ask for it!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use ORM without changing your database by creating classes from your database. You should read [this in the symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)